# C DBus : Fails when calling method returning string

Tags: c, dbus

Cant please someone tell me why the code below crashes when executing, (compilation goes OK) it in rotated X environment 90 to left.

```
    DBusGConnection *connection;
    DBusGProxy *proxy;
    GError *error = NULL;
    gchar *name = NULL;

    g_type_init ();

    //Get the connection and ensure the name is not used yet
    connection = dbus_g_bus_get (DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, &error);
    if (connection == NULL) {
            g_warning ("Failed to make connection to system bus: %s",
                            error->message);
            g_error_free (error);
            exit(1);
    }

    proxy = dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name (connection,
                    "to.some.Service",
                    "/to/some/Object",
                    "to.some.Interface" );

    dbus_g_proxy_call(proxy, "getStatus", &error, G_TYPE_INVALID, G_TYPE_STRING, &name, G_TYPE_INVALID);
    printf("Name is: %s\n", name);
    return 0;
```

Comment: If it's really only crashing when the display is rotated 90 degrees, I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with the exact service you're calling. Please specify which service it is.

Comment: The service is defined by me and I think its working OK, because I've written a analogue python script (the same as above script) which returned correct values.

Comment: Actually above code is working OK at the first start of X. But fails to run normally if the display's orientation is rotated.

Comment: Downvoted as question is specific to your code and not generally useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer. Actually the service is running in Python and the returned value was not string ... as a consequence of not being strong types in python. So returning str(status) but no status solved my problem.